# Password protected photo galleries

Tags: customization

What is the best way to password protect individual photo galleries so individual users can log in and view their user specific photo gallery?

Answer (score 2):

These plugins are nice:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-members/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/member-access/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/membership/

Answer (score 0):

Your exact requirement will match the below plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/vc-gallery/

Hope it helps anyone!